# Why is property undefined in timer instance when in interval loop?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
function UITimer(interval, callbakFunction) {
    this.t = null;
    this.isRunning = 0;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.callbackFunction = callbakFunction;
};

UITimer.prototype.timeCount = function () {
    alert(this.interval);
    this.callbackFunction();
    this.t = setTimeout(this.timeCount, this.interval);
}

UITimer.prototype.startTimer = function () {
    if (!this.isRunning) {
        this.isRunning = 1;
        this.timeCount();
    }
}

UITimer.prototype.stopTimer = function () {
    clearTimeout(this.t);
    this.isRunning = 0;
}

var uiTimer = new UITimer(5000, PhotoService.GetRandomImage);
uiTimer.startTimer();
```

The first time `this.interval = 5000`, second time it is `undefined`. I replaced the interval by a constant value but this line `this.t = setTimeout(this.timeCount, 5000);` could not run the second time. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` value gets lost when passing a function. `foo.bar()` sets `this` to `foo` inside `bar`, but when storing/passing the value and calling it later, this does not happen.

Use `.bind` to force the `this` value inside `timeCount`:

```
this.t = setTimeout(this.timeCount.bind(this), this.interval);
```

Or, pass another function that calls `timeCount`. Beware though, since `this` changes inside functions, you'd have to save a reference to the correct `this` value:

```
var _this = this; // won't change

this.t = setTimeout(function() {
    _this.timeCount(); // `_this` is the correct `this`
}, this.interval);
```